# USB hub/c-media combo - audio device not recognised - hub won't allow allow other usb audio either

Tags: raspbian, usb, audio, hub

I have an mBeat Hayman USB hub with integrated C-Media audio.

Under Raspbian, the hub is recognised as a 4 port hub, but the C-Media audio device (which is uses one of the ports) isn't recognised.

The C-Media device (`0d8c:0014`) wasn't in the latest `usb.ids` file so I added it to my local copy (it is a CM108AH Audio Controller).  There are several CM108 controllers in the `usb.ids` files with various other product codes.

When I plug in the USB hub, the hub part gets recognised, but the C-Media device is not mentioned (I tailed `/var/log/messages` and used `udevadm` monitor).

If I plug in another C-Media USB device to one of the free ports, I also get nothing.  The same device is recognised OK when plugged directly into the PI.

I had thought that the PI wasn't recognising the `vendor:product` combination, but see that an already working audio device couldn't be seen through the hub makes me think there is something wrong with the way the hub is being connected/loaded.

The hub and audio cards are recognised in both Windows and Debian.

Here is a dump of plugging it into the Debian PC.

```
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.027821] usb 1-1.1.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.122962] usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.122976] usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.122979] usb 1-1.1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.122981] usb 1-1.1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.123394] hub 1-1.1.3:1.0: USB hub found
Feb  1 15:08:15 Taylor kernel: [   66.123692] hub 1-1.1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.412118] usb 1-1.1.3.3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.518038] usb 1-1.1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0014
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.518051] usb 1-1.1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.518054] usb 1-1.1.3.3: Product: USB Audio Device
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.518056] usb 1-1.1.3.3: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.535702] input: C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Audio Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3.3/1-1.1.3.3:1.3/0003:0D8C:0014.0005/input/input15
Feb  1 15:08:16 Taylor kernel: [   66.535861] hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0014.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Audio Device] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1.3.3/input3
```

This `udevadm` monitor output shows plugging in the hub/C-Media combo, and then plugging in a the other C-Media device and a thumbdrive.

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[7841.295251] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/071
DEVNUM=071
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=70
PRODUCT=2109/2812/9090
SEQNUM=1210
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=9/0/1

KERNEL[7841.299058] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=9/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v2109p2812d9090dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=2109/2812/9090
SEQNUM=1211
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=9/0/1

UDEV  [7841.325060] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/071
DEVNUM=071
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_4
ID_MODEL=USB2.0_Hub
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB2.0\x20Hub\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=SMC9514 Hub
ID_MODEL_ID=2812
ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_4
ID_REVISION=9090
ID_SERIAL=VIA_Labs__Inc._USB2.0_Hub
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:090000:
ID_VENDOR=VIA_Labs__Inc.
ID_VENDOR_ENC=VIA\x20Labs\x2c\x20Inc.\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Standard Microsystems Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=2109
MAJOR=189
MINOR=70
PRODUCT=2109/2812/9090
SEQNUM=1210
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TAGS=:seat:
TYPE=9/0/1
USEC_INITIALIZED=41294454

UDEV  [7841.331009] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Hub
ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Single TT
INTERFACE=9/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v2109p2812d9090dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=2109/2812/9090
SEQNUM=1211
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=9/0/1
USEC_INITIALIZED=296049

KERNEL[7848.522824] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/076
DEVNUM=076
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=75
PRODUCT=781/5576/100
SEQNUM=1212
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[7848.523673] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=8/6/80
MODALIAS=usb:v0781p5576d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
PRODUCT=781/5576/100
SEQNUM=1213
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[7848.525540] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3
DEVTYPE=scsi_host
SEQNUM=1214
SUBSYSTEM=scsi

KERNEL[7848.525682] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3 (scsi_host)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3
SEQNUM=1215
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_host

UDEV  [7848.536910] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/076
DEVNUM=076
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_DRIVE_THUMB=1
ID_MODEL=Cruzer_Facet
ID_MODEL_ENC=Cruzer\x20Facet
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Cruzer Facet
ID_MODEL_ID=5576
ID_REVISION=0100
ID_SERIAL=SanDisk_Cruzer_Facet_4C530001091203122464
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=4C530001091203122464
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_VENDOR=SanDisk
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SanDisk
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=SanDisk Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=0781
MAJOR=189
MINOR=75
PRODUCT=781/5576/100
SEQNUM=1212
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=48522861

UDEV  [7848.543908] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Cruzer Facet
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=SanDisk Corp.
INTERFACE=8/6/80
MODALIAS=usb:v0781p5576d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
PRODUCT=781/5576/100
SEQNUM=1213
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=524393

UDEV  [7848.548315] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3
DEVTYPE=scsi_host
SEQNUM=1214
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=524776

UDEV  [7848.553514] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3 (scsi_host)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3
SEQNUM=1215
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_host
USEC_INITIALIZED=525083

KERNEL[7849.522380] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_target
SEQNUM=1216
SUBSYSTEM=scsi

KERNEL[7849.522510] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_device
MODALIAS=scsi:t-0x00
SEQNUM=1217
SUBSYSTEM=scsi

KERNEL[7849.522609] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_disk/3:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_disk/3:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1218
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk

KERNEL[7849.523393] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_device/3:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_device/3:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1219
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_device

KERNEL[7849.524049] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sg0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0
MAJOR=21
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1220
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_generic

KERNEL[7849.524624] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/bsg/3:0:0:0 (bsg)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/bsg/3:0:0:0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/bsg/3:0:0:0
MAJOR=252
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1221
SUBSYSTEM=bsg

KERNEL[7849.525789] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/bdi/8:0
SEQNUM=1222
SUBSYSTEM=bdi

UDEV  [7849.525900] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_target
SEQNUM=1216
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=521757

UDEV  [7849.531389] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/bdi/8:0
SEQNUM=1222
SUBSYSTEM=bdi
USEC_INITIALIZED=49526882

UDEV  [7849.534675] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_device
MODALIAS=scsi:t-0x00
SEQNUM=1217
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=522047

UDEV  [7849.540904] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_device/3:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_device/3:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1219
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_device
USEC_INITIALIZED=526424

UDEV  [7849.542865] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_disk/3:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_disk/3:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1218
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk
USEC_INITIALIZED=526160

KERNEL[7849.544836] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sda
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
DEVTYPE=disk
MAJOR=8
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1223
SUBSYSTEM=block

KERNEL[7849.544983] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sda1
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
DEVTYPE=partition
MAJOR=8
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=1224
SUBSYSTEM=block

UDEV  [7849.546656] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sg0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0
MAJOR=21
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1220
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_generic
USEC_INITIALIZED=49526596

UDEV  [7849.552143] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/bsg/3:0:0:0 (bsg)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/bsg/3:0:0:0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/bsg/3:0:0:0
MAJOR=252
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1221
SUBSYSTEM=bsg
USEC_INITIALIZED=49526757

UDEV  [7849.655860] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Facet_4C530001091203122464-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
DEVNAME=/dev/sda
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
DEVTYPE=disk
ID_BUS=usb
ID_DRIVE_THUMB=1
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=Cruzer_Facet
ID_MODEL_ENC=Cruzer\x20Facet\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=5576
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_4_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=1.00
ID_SERIAL=SanDisk_Cruzer_Facet_4C530001091203122464-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=4C530001091203122464
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=SanDisk
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SanDisk\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=0781
MAJOR=8
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1223
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:systemd:
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_COUNT=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=mbr
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
USEC_INITIALIZED=544893

UDEV  [7849.791752] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Facet_4C530001091203122464-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/F040-35E6
DEVNAME=/dev/sda1
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
DEVTYPE=partition
ID_BUS=usb
ID_DRIVE_THUMB=1
ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
ID_FS_UUID=F040-35E6
ID_FS_UUID_ENC=F040-35E6
ID_FS_VERSION=FAT32
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=Cruzer_Facet
ID_MODEL_ENC=Cruzer\x20Facet\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=5576
ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:0
ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=32
ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=15630304
ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0xb
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_4_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=1.00
ID_SERIAL=SanDisk_Cruzer_Facet_4C530001091203122464-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=4C530001091203122464
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=SanDisk
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SanDisk\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=0781
MAJOR=8
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=1224
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:systemd:
UDISKS_PARTITION=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT_OFFSET=0
UDISKS_PARTITION_NUMBER=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_OFFSET=16384
UDISKS_PARTITION_SCHEME=mbr
UDISKS_PARTITION_SIZE=8002715648
UDISKS_PARTITION_SLAVE=/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
UDISKS_PARTITION_TYPE=0x0b
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
USEC_INITIALIZED=545181
```

I didn't get a `udev` monitor of doing the same on the Debian PC though.

Is the hub not being loaded properly?  It looks like just audio cards aren't being detected through it (although I have only tried a thumbdrive).  The hub's USB ID (`2109:2812`) wasn't in my original  `usb.ids` file, so perhaps it is a new model?

Does `ehci-pci` have anything to do with it? The Debian machine reports

> new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci

Raspbian reports

> new full-speed USB device number 83 using dwc_otg

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have just this page which shows a limitation of usb 3 hubs and usb 2 devices.  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify my comment above, here is an extract from the linked page.

> **1. Interoperability between the Raspberry Pi and USB3.0 hubs**
>
> There is an issue with USB3.0 hubs in conjunction with the use of Full- or
> Low-speed devices (most mice, most keyboards) and the Raspberry Pi. A
> bug in most USB3.0 hub hardware means that the Raspberry Pi cannot
> talk to Full- or Low-speed devices connected to a USB3.0 hub.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.

When you modified the `usb.ids`, did you reboot your device to see if the changes you made to the file will indeed work?

Comment: I am fairly sure I did, but it was over 2.5 years ago.  I am confident it was the hub hardware problem I mentioned.